# Move mobile nav from left to right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move mobile navigation from top left corner and slide in from left side to the right side. I've tried to change position settings from left to right, but it didn't work.
I will really appreciate any help!

Code below, thank you!

```css
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

&:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate3d(-240px, 0, 0);
  transition: transform 0.35s;
}

label.menu-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  right: -60px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 0px;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: transparent url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-512.png) 50% 50% / 25px 25px no-repeat;
}

label.active {
  background: transparent url(menu-cross.png) 50% 50% / 25px 25px no-repeat;
}

ul li>label {
  background: url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-right-b-128.png) 95% 50% / 16px 16px no-repeat;
}

a,
label {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 30px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #000;
}

&:hover {
  color: #666;
}
   
.menu-checkbox{
    display: none;
}

   
.menu .menu label.menu-toggle {
     background: none;
}    

.menu-checkbox:checked + .menu {
     transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" id="menub" name="menu" class="menu-checkbox">
  <div class="menu">
    <label class="menu-toggle" for="menub"><span>Toggle</span></label>
    <ul>

      <li>
        <a href="">link</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">link</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">link</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- #wrapper -->
```

Comment: post your html, too, so we have a [mcve]

Comment: @MichaelCoker There it is, HTML added

Comment: thanks. please also post your compiled CSS. we shouldn't have to compile it for you.

Comment: @MichaelCoker sorry for that. I've edited CSS again, because I forgot to add settings for inputs..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe you have overcomplicated your task. You could simply open new project on visual studio and go from there.  This would be the best option, since the result you want to achieve is most likely the same.

Now if you do want to stick to this, you must go carefully through your style code and what could be preventing the item to align on the right side.

Comment: What? How is Visual Studio relevant to this question at all? -1.